# xrotate script for ubuntu touch missing

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I installed ubuntu touch ota-15 on my Nexus 7 2013 (wifi-only edition) and it looks great! However, it's stuck in portrait mode. I can't get it to switch to landscape mode. I did a little research and found out there was a script called xrotate located in /usr/bin directory but it's not there (anymore). How do I get it or maybe there's a different way to rotate the screen? Thanks!